# sorting in javascript based on index

Tags: javascript, output

I am kind of naive in javascript,I need to sort an array of elements in form of Tij, based on the j value.

Input: T31, T64, T03, T98.
Output:T31,T03,T64,T98

T is constant element, and i and j is variable. I want to sort just elements based on j index.(i and j are both index).

Is there any method that I can use in javascript?I do not have any idea what I can do?

Thanks for help,

Comment: Where have you looked for answers?  What have you tried?

Comment: @HereticMonkey: This is not clearly a duplication.  It's hard to tell for sure from the brief question, but "based on the j value" makes me think that we can't pull out the only number in the inputs.

Comment: @nazi Please can you provide a sample input and output.

Comment: @ScottSauyet The OP is free to [edit] their question to provide more information to demonstrate that the duplicate is not correct. At least, that's what the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) says...

Comment: @HereticMonkey: of course, and given the lack of effort  by the OP, this doesn't upset me.  But I don't like calling a question a duplicate when neither the other question nor its answers are particularly close.

Comment: Do a favor to me GUYS. Please read the question carefully, then marked it as Duplicate. IT IS TOTALLY A DIFFERENT QUESTION.

Comment: @amrendersingh:I edited the question, and give the output and input

Comment: @HereticMonkey:it is not duplicate question. even if it is, the other question is not answered properly or even it is not closed.

Comment: @nazikth I've voted to reopen the question, which is the best I can do. Note that yelling (which is what all caps translates to) is not a good tactic. Note also that had you put the inputs and outputs in the question in the first place, there would have been no doubt as to its unique nature. Finally, it is always a good idea to try solving the problem yourself, or at least search for ways of doing so, and report the research in the question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: Thanks for help, lol...I did not yell at anyone. But it was better idea to read the question before just remark it. Obviously, I tried myself at first before I asked and I believe the main reason of stack Overflow is to collaborate with the people to help you in the topic u are not good at. And i didnot mean to waste anyone s time.Anyways, Thanks for effective help.

Comment: I read the original question and found nothing there to show that it was not a duplicate. Stack Overflow's purpose is not to help a single person in a topic they are not good at. It is to be a library of knowledge, gleaned from high-quality questions and answers that will allow many people to be helped, not just a single individual. Keep that in mind when preparing to ask questions on Stack Overflow and you will be better off.

Comment: Well, as u like . I can't understand u thoughts, it is duplicate or not. Each comment ,ur idea is different. I don't mind . But as a PHD student in computer science , I am totally aware of the purpose of stackoverflow,  but my first time to see people don't even try to read the question. It is totally ok. I don't want to continue this , I will figure it out myself, good luck guys

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom sort that just related to the `j` character:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a[2] - b[2];
});
```

**Edit:**

The OP didn't define how to break ties, but using the `i` character seems like a reasonable decision:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
  var res = a[2] - b[2];
  if (res == 0) {
    res = a[1] - b[1];
  }
  return res;
});
```

Comment: Note to posterity: This answer made more sense before the question was edited, at least by my reading. I think the elements `T_31` etc were just strings `'T31'`.

Comment: @DavidKnipe I think you meant "before the question was edited". Your edit to the answer was definitely on point.

Comment: Thanks @Mureinik. I'm glad I got that corrected before the 5-minute deadline.

Comment: @Mureinik: Thanks man. I just dont figure out why you use res=a[2]-b[2]?

Comment: @nazikth `[2]` is the third character in the string - the "j"

Comment: @Mureinik: j and i are both index. I still can not figure out why we need to use var res = a[2] - b[2];